# laravel appending value to a variable from loop

Tags: php, laravel

How can I set a value of a variable? The value will come from the loop

```
$foo = ''; // empty variable

foreach ($test as $index) {
    $index->name;
}
```

I want to set the value of `$foo` from the `$index->name;`

so If I access the `$foo` it will now show the value of `$index->name;`

tried this but it didn't work:

```
$foo = ''; // empty variable
        
foreach ($test as $index) {
    $foo = $index->name;
}

echo $foo; // still empty
```

Comment: What is `$test`? It must be an iterable (such as an array). Meaning it may contain multiple values, or just none at all (which appears to be your case).

Answer (score -1):

Be aware that value of `$foo` will be the last `$index->name` in `$test` collection

```
$foo = ''; // empty variable

foreach ($test as $index) {
   $foo = $index->name;
}
```

Comment: as what I've included to the question. I tried that approach. Thank you